# Checking if String entered is a binary numer, getting incorrect output

Tags: java, string, binary

I am trying to write a program that will check if the user-entered string is a binary number, and if it is, it will output the number of 1s in the number.  I had this working fine with an integer value, but since an int can't hold more than 2 billion or whatever the max value is, I am trying to rewrite it to work with Strings.

As of right now, any number I enter will output "Number entered is not binary." and when I enter 0, I will get a StringIndexOutofBoundsException. I am a fairly novice programmer, so forgive any obvious errors I may have missed, I am just asking for a possible solution to my problem or a push in the right direction.  Here is my code (after trying to make it work with Strings rather than integers):

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class BinaryHW {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
  String bin = kb.nextLine();

  //the method I used to check whether or not user entered a binary
  //number requires changing the value of 'bin'.
  //Therefore, 'origBin' set equal to 'bin' for later use.

  String origBin = bin;
  int count = 0;

  boolean isBinary = true;
  /* if bin = 0, then this loop will be skipped because 
   * 0 is a binary number and need not be checked.
   */

  while (Integer.parseInt(bin) != 0) {

     int lastDigit = bin.charAt(bin.length() - 1);

     if (lastDigit > 1) {
        System.out.println("Number entered is not binary.");
        isBinary = false;
        break;

     } else {
        bin = bin.substring(bin.length() - 2);
     }
  }  
  //Again, the method I used to count the 1s in the bin number
  //requires changing the value of origBin, so origBin2 is introduced 

  String origBin2 = origBin;

  for (int i = 0; i < origBin.length(); i++) {

     if (origBin.charAt(origBin.length() - 1) == 1) {
        count ++;
        origBin2 = origBin.substring(origBin2.length() - 2);

     } else {
        origBin2 = origBin.substring(origBin2.length() - 2);

     }

  }  

  if (isBinary)
     if (count == 1)
     System.out.println("There is " 
        + count + " 1 in the binary number entered.");
     else 
     System.out.println("There are " 
        + count + " 1s in the binary number entered.");

     }
 }
```

Comment: Your for loop makes absolutely no sense. What are you trying to accomplish? Of course you are going to get an index out of bounds when you call `origBin2.length() - 2` on a string with the length of 1

Comment: You were also confused by character "1" and hex 1, that's why you always get "number entered is not binary"

Comment: Jonathan, you need to really spend some time reading the documentation of your methods you are trying to use.

Comment: red, my for loop worked perfectly fine when the input was an integer, I just quickly (bold/underline on quickly) tried to change things to work with a string but obviously that didn't work, which is why I asked for help.  appreciate the input but no need to be so condescending.

Comment: thank you ethan, that was an obvious one that I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things... simply iterate through your binary string, and keep track of the number of 1's reached. If a number other than 0 or 1 is found, report that input is a non-binary number. Below is a snippet which accomplishes this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
      String bin = kb.nextLine();
      int oneCount = 0;
      boolean validBinaryNum = true;

      for (int i = 0; i < bin.length() && validBinaryNum; i++) {
          char currentChar = bin.charAt(i);
          if (currentChar == '1') oneCount++;
          else if (currentChar != '0') {
              validBinaryNum = false;
          }
      }

      if (validBinaryNum && bin.length() != 0) {
          System.out.println("Number of 1's: " + oneCount);
      } else {
          System.out.println("Number is not binary");
      }

}
```